# Make a SQL Stored Procedure find more than the exact string

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, match

I have this stored procedure that returns matches against a couple tables based on a query. But say I search for the word 'asset', it will only return things with the exact word 'asset' and not for example 'assets'.

I have a series of `MATCH`'s going on and I just recently tried to concat the `_query` with some `%` symbols to try and use as a wild card but that doesn't seem to be doing anything.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`database` PROCEDURE `search_terms`(
  IN _query varchar(60)
)
BEGIN
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';
SELECT
    dictionary.id,
    dictionary.`term`,
    dictionary.`definition`,
    links.id AS `linkId`,
    links.`name`,
    links.`url`,
    links.term_id
FROM ItDictionary dictionary
    LEFT JOIN ItRelatedLinks links ON links.term_id = dictionary.id
WHERE MATCH(dictionary.term, dictionary.definition)
AGAINST(CONCAT( '%', _query, '%') IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
    OR MATCH(links.name)
AGAINST(CONCAT( '%', _query, '%') IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
ORDER BY MATCH(dictionary.term, dictionary.definition)
AGAINST(CONCAT( '%', _query, '%') IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
    + MATCH(links.name)
AGAINST(CONCAT( '%', _query, '%') IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) DESC;
END
```

This may be overkill, I'm pretty new to SQL, but it works pretty well (sans the concat / % part) and not being able to match the query with words that contain said query.

Is there a way to slightly modify this or should I take a whole different approach?

Thanks!

Comment: In the docs, the `%` is also not used.... see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html.   `MATCH` works differently than `LIKE`, for `LIKE` see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: Hey, thanks for the clarification. In any example I see using LIKE with a stored procedure parameter it's like this `dictionary.term LIKE '%' + @the_query + '%'` but I keep getting an error "+" is not valid at this position. I'm attempting to chain it with `OR` like so: `dictionary.term LIKE '%' + @the_query + '%'
    OR dictionary.definition LIKE '%' + @the_query + '%'
    OR links.name LIKE '%' + @the_query + '%';` and the very first `+` is throwing the error

Comment: I believe I got it. Not sure what I did different this time around other than changing my parameter type back to varchar. but chaining these `dictionary.term LIKE CONCAT('%', _query, '%')` is producing more accurate results. Thanks @Luuk